# How to set a different connection timeout for specific service in OkHttp 3?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

In my application, all my services has `60 seconds connection timeout` except one service has 3 minutes. However I can only set one timeout for OkHttp 3? Is it possible to set 180 seconds for that `specific service`?

```
OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClient = newOkHttpClient.Builder()

                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

retrofit:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .client(okHttpClient.build())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the HTTP client configuration lives in OkHttpClient including proxy settings, timeouts, and caches. When you need to change the configuration of a single call, call OkHttpClient.newBuilder(). This returns a builder that shares the same connection pool, dispatcher, and configuration with the original client.

In example below, we make one request with a 500 ms timeout and another with a 3000 ms timeout.

```
private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

public void run() throws Exception {
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("http://httpbin.org/delay/1") // This URL is served with a 1 second delay.
    .build();

// Copy to customize OkHttp for this request.
OkHttpClient client1 = client.newBuilder()
    .readTimeout(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .build();
try (Response response = client1.newCall(request).execute()) {
  System.out.println("Response 1 succeeded: " + response);
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Response 1 failed: " + e);
}

// Copy to customize OkHttp for this request.
OkHttpClient client2 = client.newBuilder()
    .readTimeout(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .build();
try (Response response = client2.newCall(request).execute()) {
  System.out.println("Response 2 succeeded: " + response);
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Response 2 failed: " + e);
}
}
```

So you need to create different client for each request.

Comment: You can also customize in an [interceptor](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Interceptor.Chain.html).

Comment: @JesseWilson is this going to change my Headers? Session Id etc? because all of my services are related but only one of them has different timeout

Comment: @JesseWilson I tried but it's overriding/modifying timeout of original request.